# Why does the change ft_min_word_len have no effect?

Tags: mysql, search

I have set the ft_min_word_len to 3, so a simple search like this:

```
SELECT * FROM store_product_description WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('lag' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

should work, but it doesn't. The column "name" is a varchar with fulltext index.

Comment: If the word is present in [mysql fulltext stopwords list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) it will be ignored. "lag" certainly isn't in that list btw, so can you tell us what other words aren't matching?

Comment: I have tried with VGS and LES, have not any other words with 3 letters.

Comment: @FulvioFutreCorsini Engine??? index type??

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you'll have to recreate your FULLTEXT indexes if you wish your changes to minimum/maximum length and stopwords to apply to existing indexed rows.